# How can I launch Chrome in App mode full screen

Tags: google-chrome

I am installing a shortcut to launch Chrome to launch our website.

I'd like to launch it in -App mode but then it doesn't launch full screen.
(If the user makes it full screen once, it seems to "remember" that, but our users are brain injured and can't be dependended on to know how to make it full screen.

**I tried:**
--kiosk  mode (had no effect)
--start-maximized  -App=    -still started out not maximized

Comment: Does [kiosk mode](http://askubuntu.com/questions/358898/how-to-launch-google-chrome-chromium-application-shortcut-in-fullscreen-kiosk-mo) work for you?

Comment: No. Kiosk mode had no effect.